# How do I receive APNS silent push message payload in a web page on safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement Safari Web Push using the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW24) to setup APNS and receive silent push messages on a react app on Safari browser.

At this point, I have added an endpoint to get push packages on calling window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission. This prompts the user to enable notification and grants the permission and returns with a device token.

I have a server-side node script implemented using [node-apn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-apn) to send a silent push message to the client using a device token. The send function resolves with a successful response.

Sample message packet that I am sending via APNS:

```json
{
  "aps": {
    "content-available": 1
  },
  "customData": "custom data",
  "topic": "web.push.ID"
}
```

I am expecting the payload to be delivered to the client through an event.
I am trying this with the below function on the web page.

```js
window.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    if (event && event.push) {
        const payload = event.push;
        console.log('safari received payload in window.addEventListener:', payload);
    }
});
```

However, I do not see any message coming to the client.

Can someone please point me to what I am missing here?
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.